# Sqlite3 problem with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rvm

I had a project with rails 3 and ruby 1.8.7 then I installed rvm and ruby 1.9.2 now when I try to run script/rails console in the project folder, I get this error with SQLlite

```
/home/khaled/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]Aborted
```

Help ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, If you are using Rails 3 it's `rails console`, `rails server`, not `script/console`, `script/server`

Second, see if rvm is working properly with `rvm` in you console. If you get good output then you are ok. If not you need to install rvm properly [here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).

Switch versions of ruby with rvm use `ruby-1.9.3xxxx`. You can get the ruby versions with `rvm list`. Try install different versions and see if that helps out.